# Queryset more funcionally

Tags: django, django-models

I have a question whether the code is acceptable, or is there another possibility with a more optimal way out of this situation
My one model look like that:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  manga = models.ManyToManyField(Manga, through='ModelB') 

  def manga_list(self):
    return ModelB.objects.filter(user=self.pk).all()

  def manga_list_reading(self):
    return ModelB.objects.filter(user=self.pk, type=utils.READING).all()
```

and second model look like that:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
  manga = models.ForeignKey(Manga, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=utils.LIST_PROFILE_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
```

so my question is about this def list return, is it some another option for do it ?

Comment: `self.modelb_set.all()` for the `manga_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `manga_list` can be queried with:

```
self.modelb_set.all()  # ModelB objects
```

It thus does not make much sense to specify a method for this, since you can query this with `my_model_a.modelb_set.all()`. Furthermore naming this `manga_list` is a bit "misleading", since the queryset will return `ModelB` objects, not `Manga` objects. If you want to return all `Manga` objects linked by the `ModelB`, you can do this with:

```
my_model_a.manga.all()  # Manga objects
```

If you want to retrieve the `Manga` objects for which the type is `READING`, you can retrieve these with:

```
my_model_a.manga.filter(modelb__type=utils.READING)  # Manga objects
```